# Selected Index Change event of dropdwonlist in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am very new to MVC and Presently I need to work on a Project in MVC4 with Razor engine.

So can any one tell me about

How to implement logic for SelectedIndex Change event of dropdwonlist in MVC4?

Thanks.

Comment: There are no server-side events in MVC like you may be used to from ASP.NET WebForms. In fact there is no server side in MVC at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC you can't do this. You'd need to use jQuery. OnSelectedIndexChange is a concept that is used in ASP.Net, and MVC3 is vastly different. If you want to implement logic when a user changes a DDL, you'd need a jQuery function to run when the DDL changes (`onchange` html attribute), which would then pass a request with AJAX to a controller on your page. Within this controller you'd be able to implement this logic.

I'd recommend getting familar with the concepts of MVC first. Practises in ASP.Net are rarely interchangeable with MVC.